# No logro recuperar lista de mi realtime Database de Firebase

Tags: java, android, base-de-datos, firebase

Estoy intentando recuperar los datos de mi database en Android Studio con Java y llenar un recylerView con una clase ActividadesAdapter.java y Actividades.java y mostrarlos en mi Activity ListAct.java:
Agradezco cualquier posible solucion la idea es retornar las actividades que contengan el campo estado y sea igual a pendiente.

Esta es mi clase ListAct.java donde quiero mostrar mis datos:

```
 public class ListaAct extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseReference mDatabase;
    public ActividadesAdapter actividadesAdapter;
    public RecyclerView recyclerView;
    public ArrayList<Actividades> mArrayList;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_lista);
        //setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_PORTRAIT); //Función que se encarga de bloquear la rotación de pantalla

        mArrayList = new ArrayList<>();
        actividadesAdapter = new ActividadesAdapter(mArrayList,R.layout.row_recycler_act);
        recyclerView = findViewById(R.id.rvActividades);
        recyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));
        recyclerView.setAdapter(actividadesAdapter);
        mDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("DataLegalizaciones");
        getActividadesFromFirebase();

    }
    private void getActividadesFromFirebase(){

        mDatabase.child("Actividades").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        String itm = ds.getValue(Actividades.class).toString();
                        mArrayList.add(new Actividades(itm));
                        actividadesAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
                    }
                    actividadesAdapter = new ActividadesAdapter(mArrayList,R.layout.row_recycler_act);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(actividadesAdapter);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });

    }
}
```

Este es el adaptador:

```
public class ActividadesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<ActividadesAdapter.ViewHolder>{

    int resource;
    private ArrayList<Actividades> actividadesList;
    public ActividadesAdapter(ArrayList<Actividades> actividadesList, int resource){
        this.actividadesList = actividadesList;
        this.resource = resource;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View mView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(resource,parent,false);

        return new ViewHolder(mView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder holder, int position) {

        Actividades actividades = actividadesList.get(position);
        holder.tvNombreA.setText(actividades.getNombreActividad());
        holder.tvNumeroP.setText(actividades.getNumeroProjecto());
        holder.tvValorP.setText(actividades.getValorPresupuesto());
        holder.tvTipoA.setText(actividades.getTipoActividad());
        holder.tvFechaA.setText(actividades.getFechaActividad());
        holder.tvEstadoA.setText(actividades.getEstado());
        holder.tvUsuarioA.setText(actividades.getUsuario());

    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return actividadesList.size();
    }

    public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder{
        TextView tvNombreA;
        TextView tvNumeroP;
        TextView tvValorP;
        TextView tvTipoA;
        TextView tvFechaA;
        TextView tvEstadoA;
        TextView tvUsuarioA;
        public View view;
        public ViewHolder(View view){
            super(view);
            this.view = view;
            this.tvNombreA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNombreA);
            this.tvNumeroP = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvNumeroP);
            this.tvValorP = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvValorP);
            this.tvTipoA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvTipoA);
            this.tvFechaA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvFechaA);
            this.tvEstadoA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvEstadoA);
            this.tvUsuarioA = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.tvUsuarioA);
        }
    }
}
```

Y la clase Actividades.java que funciona como modelo:

```
public class Actividades {
    String estado,fechaActividad,nombreActividad,numeroProjecto,tipoActividad,usuario,valorPresupuesto;
    //public Actividades(){ }
    public Actividades(String itm) { }

    public Actividades(String estado, String fechaActividad, String nombreActividad,String numeroProjecto, String tipoActividad, String usuario, String valorPresupuesto) {
        this.estado = estado;
        this.fechaActividad = fechaActividad;
        this.nombreActividad = nombreActividad;
        this.numeroProjecto = numeroProjecto;
        this.tipoActividad = tipoActividad;
        this.usuario = usuario;
        this.valorPresupuesto = valorPresupuesto;
    }

    public String getEstado() {
        return estado;
    }

    public void setEstado(String estado) {
        this.estado = estado;
    }

    public String getFechaActividad() {
        return fechaActividad;
    }

    public void setFechaActividad(String fechaActividad) {
        this.fechaActividad = fechaActividad;
    }

    public String getNombreActividad() {
        return nombreActividad;
    }

    public void setNombreActividad(String nombreActividad) {
        this.nombreActividad = nombreActividad;
    }

    public String getTipoActividad() {
        return tipoActividad;
    }

    public void setTipoActividad(String tipoActividad) {
        this.tipoActividad = tipoActividad;
    }

    public String getUsuario() {
        return usuario;
    }

    public void setUsuario(String usuario) {
        this.usuario = usuario;
    }

    public String getValorPresupuesto() {
        return valorPresupuesto;
    }

    public void setValorPresupuesto(String valorPresupuesto) {
        this.valorPresupuesto = valorPresupuesto;
    }


    public String getNumeroProjecto() {
        return numeroProjecto;
    }

    public void setNumeroProjecto(String numeroProjecto) {
        this.numeroProjecto = numeroProjecto;
    }
}
```

Este es el mensaje que arroja mi Logcat:

```
2019-09-04 14:24:11.331 14380-14380/pv.portafolioverde.ftsapp E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: pv.portafolioverde.ftsapp, PID: 14380
    com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseException: Class pv.portafolioverde.ftsapp.Actividades does not define a no-argument constructor. If you are using ProGuard, make sure these constructors are not stripped.
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:552)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper$BeanMapper.deserialize(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:545)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertBean(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:415)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.deserializeToClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:214)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.utilities.encoding.CustomClassMapper.convertToCustomClass(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:79)
        at com.google.firebase.database.DataSnapshot.getValue(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:212)
        at pv.portafolioverde.ftsapp.ListaAct$1.onDataChange(ListaAct.java:44)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.ValueEventRegistration.fireEvent(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:75)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.DataEvent.fire(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:63)
        at com.google.firebase.database.core.view.EventRaiser$1.run(com.google.firebase:firebase-database@@18.0.1:55)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:751)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6351)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:896)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:786)
```

Agradezco cualquier posible solucion la idea es retornar las actividades que contengan el campo estado y sea igual a pendiente.
Tambien intente camiando la linea de codigo:

```
String itm = ds.getValue(Actividades.class).toString();
```

Por:

```
String itm = ds.getValue(ActividadesAdapter.class).toString();
```

[image]

Es decir, quiero se vean solo las actividades que han sido aprobadas, lo he logrado con firestore por medio de whereEqualsTo("aprobado") pero en realtime database no lo he conseguido aun..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

En tu clase Actividades necesitas tener un constructor vacio para poder parsear los datos desde Firebase

```
public class Actividades {
...
public Actividades() { }

}
```

Ademas, cuando notificas datos al adapter, no hace falta que uses `notifySetDataChange()` si estas creando una nueva instancia del adapter una vez traido todos los datos

```
mDatabase.child("Actividades").addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                if (dataSnapshot.exists()){
                    for (DataSnapshot ds: dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
                        Actividades actividades = ds.getValue(Actividades.class);
                        mArrayList.add(actividades);
                    }
                    actividadesAdapter = new ActividadesAdapter(mArrayList,R.layout.row_recycler_act);
                    recyclerView.setAdapter(actividadesAdapter);
                }
            }
            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {
            }
        });
```

Con esos campos deberia funcionar

Comment: Muchas gracias @Gastón me has ayudado bastante! pero estoy intentando además llamar las actividades que contengan como valor aprobado el campo estado ya agregué como se ve la estructura de mi database.

Comment: tal vez tienes material o tienes codigo de como puedo actualizar ese campo estado de mis actividades desde google sheets? estoy leyendo ya la database de firebase en mi hoja de calculo pero necesito que otro usuario desde la hoja pueda modificar el estado a aprobado y que se actualice en firebase por medio de google script?

Answer (score 1):

lo que necesitaba era esto:

```
.orderByChild("estado").equalTo("aprobado")
```

muchas gracias igual esto podria servirle a alguien de la comunidad